# javascript Dynamically change a nested view in angularjs ui-router ui-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a template which is nested inside another template which I want to load when i click on a button.
So the nested template is loaded dynamically. This is what I have done so far.

```
<div ui-view="{{template_name}}">
</div>
```

The above does not load the template as I expected.
But when I put a template name directly like below, it loads it fully

```
<div ui-view="page1">
</div>
```

What can I do for it to load the template dynamically

Comment: You need to be using nested routes/views here.

Comment: it is already a nested view